# Custom URL for Google sites says www is already taken

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-sites

When I try to setup a [Custom URL for a new google sites](https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/sites/address) it says "Custom URL already taken"

[image: Sites "Add custom URL" dialog]

Looking at [Company Profile, Custom URLs](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?hl=en_GB&fral=1#CompanyProfile:flyout=customUrl) There is no custom URLs set.

[image]

Where else can I look to find and release the taken `www`?

Answer (score 3):

**Find what service is currently using `www`**

Connect to ghs.googlehosted.com using your domain name.
There are several options, choose one of them.

- Configure your DNS for the `www` with CNAME to `ghs.googlehosted.com`
- Add `172.217.21.179 www.example.com` to your `/etc/hosts`
- Check the response directly: `curl -v http://ghs.googelhosted.com -H "Host: www.example.com"`

In my case the returning site was **blogger**.

Blogger is not part of the GSuite core services and in my GSuite-account it was disabled.
Enable the blogger service won't help as there is no interface in the admin panel to disable the custom URL.

**Solution**

Although Google-sites custom URL refuse to use `www` others don't complain.

1. Go to the [Company Custom URL page](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?hl=en_GB&fral=1#CompanyProfile:flyout=customUrl)
2. Pick any service and set www as it's custom URL.
3. Save and confirm that you have made the changes in DNS(even though you haven't)
4. Change it back, remove `www` from that service.
5. Save and confirm again.

*Explanation:* When there is a lingering reserved custom URL of `www` pointing to blogger, step 3 will overwrite it. Step 5 will then free it.
You can review the progress by applying the top troubleshooting steps as you apply the changes.

In step 1 `ghs.googlehosted.com` will still serve blogger.
After step 3 it will serve a redirect to the service you picked.
After step 5 it will show a simple 404 page. This is how you know you have successfully freed the Custom URL `www`.
[image: Google Hosted 404 page]

**Configure Custom URL**

Now you can go to the [custom URL panel](https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/sites/address) and successfully use the `www` subdomain for your google sites.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.

Comment: @hultqvist, I have the same issue and have spend hours with Google who can't figure this out. I tried adding and deleting a custom URL for another service, but it won't let me add. I'm unclear on your instructions for finding out what service is using this custom URL. I haven't set up this domain AFAIK in the past so I can't imagine where the URL would be used.

Comment: @myklbykl I never used blogger either. The three bullets represent three different methods to achieve the same thing. The third option is quickest if you have access to a terminal with curl. The first option is probably more familiar as you would configure CNAME during the website setup.

Comment: @hultqvist — thank you for the feedback. The first time I tried the curl option I got an error because there's a typo in your example above and I just copy and pasted it. Now I'm not sure how to read the results as they don't seem to tell me anything other than "Server: ESF". I've been trying for weeks to have Google figure out the problem and they can't. The Admin console also won't allow me to set any of the other services (like mail, e.g.) to www, so that workaround isn't fixing it unfortunately.